Autodesk Vault API - Connection exception - DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComponentBase exception
I'm trying to trigger the vault Login form to get connected by using the UI.
However the following error shows up:

Here is the code:
namespace API_Onboarding_ConsoleApp1{
 internal class Program{
      static void Main(string[] args){
                    VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.Connection _connection = VDF.Vault.Forms.Library.Login(null);
        Console.WriteLine(_connection.IsConnected);    
       }
  }
}

By the way, the same error is thrown by cloning the repo used in this AU class: https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Using-Vault-Forge-Design-Automation-Inventor-2020
since I'm using the same commands.
I've also tried to connect without using the UI as follows:
 string server = "https://xxxxxxxxxx";
    string vault = "xxxxx";
    string username = "xxxxx";
    string password = "xxxxx";

    // Create a connection to the Vault
    VDF.Vault.Results.LogInResult results =
        VDF.Vault.Library.ConnectionManager.LogIn(server, vault, username, password, VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.AuthenticationFlags.Standard, null);

    VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.Connection connection = null;
    if (results.Success)
    {
        connection = results.Connection;
    }


    Console.WriteLine(results.Success);
    Console.WriteLine(results.Connection);

However, I still getting a false connection success value:

